# Test for existence and correct value on an if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, coffeescript, operators

With JavaScript or CoffeeScript, is there an easy way to test for the following:

```
if (locals.messages.text === "somestring") { ... }
```

Now this needs three things to be true: `locals` needs to exist,  `locals.messages` needs to exist and it needs to equal to `"somestring"`.

If `locals.messages` doesn't exist, it throws a `TypeEror cannot read text of undefined`

I know I can do this:

```
if (!!locals && !!locals.messages && locals.messages.text == "somestring) {...}
```

but that is too long, is there anyway to:

1. text for the existance of `locals.messages.text`
2. Check if the value is equal to something?

Working in either javascript or coffeescript

Comment: You can do it with a try/catch

Comment: To me, "testing for existence" implies that the `locals` can't be resolved (a ReferenceError). This is asking how to deep-query an object graph path when intermediate nodes may evaluate to undefined. (The JavaScript-only solution is not nearly as pretty.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In CoffeeScript you can use the accessor variant of the "Existential Operator", roughly:

```
locals?.messages?.text == 'somestring'
```

http://coffeescript.org/

This compiles to (broken up for clarity, but not really any more readable):

```
(typeof locals !== "undefined" && locals !== null 
    ? (_ref = locals.messages) != null 
        ? _ref.text 
        : void 0 
    : void 0)
    === 'somestring'
```

> The accessor variant of the existential operator `?.` can be used to soak up null references in a chain of properties. Use it instead of the dot accessor `.` in cases where the base value may be null or undefined. If all of the properties exist then you'll get the expected result, if the chain is broken, undefined is returned instead of the TypeError that would be raised otherwise.

Not sure if it meets your *precise* requirements, but it may be enough.

Comment: +1 Looks nice in Coffeescript, but compiles to some seriously ugly Javascript

Comment: @Xotic750 Sure, transcompilers generally output code you wouldn't write by hand.